# Expressions idiomatiques avec avoir

Tags: grammaire, expressions, verbes, futur

I am wondering how to use idiomatic expressions with avoir in the future tense.

To say "we are hot", we would say "nous avons chaud."

Do we still use the idiomatic expression in the future tense? How would it be phrased to indicate we are talking about the future?

Comment: You might **write** *nous avons chaud* but you would **say** *on a chaud*.

Answer (score 4):

You would simply use the future tense or use the auxiliary *aller* with infinitive construction. In your example, to say, "we will be hot," we would say "nous aurons chaud" or "nous allons avoir chaud."

This also extends to other constructions with *avoir*. Some other examples from the internet:

- **avoir soif/faim:** Après un jeûne de Yom Kippour, vous aurez souvent plus soif que faim. (*After fasting for Yom Kippur, you will generally be more thirsty than hungry.*)
- **avoir tort:** Vous aurez tort de rater [tel ou tel évènement]. (*You will be wrong to miss [such or such an event].*)
- **avoir honte:** Vous aurez honte devant l'histoire. (*You will be ashamed in the eyes of history.*)
- **avoir froid:** Nous allons avoir froid. (*We will be cold.*)

Comment: When modified like this, is it still considered an idiomatic expression?

Comment: @CanadianGirl: Yes, it's essentially just another conjugated form of the expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!